# Ensuring message order correctness in case of socket failure?

Tags: c#, sockets

how to ensure message order correctness while transfereing messages through sockets? Is there any specific design to follow? please suggest some methods...

Comment: Your question is unclear. What order are you considering?

Comment: what kind of sockets and connection / protocols are you using? TCP over IP is connection oriented and should ensure you correct order. But it depends on what you are doing and how you are using it.

Comment: Use TCP (with your own message boundaries) or SCTP?

Comment: TCP or UDP ? and what do you mean by message order ? the order between messages sent seqencialy from the same source (TCP handles that for you). the order between messages sent from different sources ? (that is problem specific and requires more info from you).

Answer (score 1):

If it is a TCP socket, then support for dropped packets etc is built into the TCP stack automatically. You don't need to do anything, except note that dropped packets may cause a brief blip as the packets are re-sent. This happens all the time: nobody notices (except people who write switches etc).

If you are trying to handle connections that break completely: that depends on your protocol. If you are doing request/response per message, then it is simple - but you pay lots of latency overhead. Some protocols work completely independently in terms of request / response (you don't stop for the response every time you send a request - you just keep sending requests, and responses will come back at some point in the future). In that setup, you will have to design around it: maybe to the last *known* response, but that still means some things may have been processed without you hearing back. So: you might want to make all actions safe to repeat, so you can just issue it again if you sent it but don't know if it completed.

If you are using UDP, then the answer is "entirely you; that is your problem; you need to figure it out", which usually means embedding a sequence number in each packet. Of course, if you are using UDP you are probably designing to simply *allow* dropped packets, and resync shortly in the future.

Answer (score 0):

TCP delivers data in the order sent. UDP does not. If you have an error that causes TCP to fail, which is very rare, you have to start over.  UDP doesn't guarantee delivery, so you need to add a protocol on top of it to request retransmission and apply sequencing. Use TCP or do your own sequence checking.